# Sorting a string by character frequency

Tags: list, haskell

I'm just starting out on using Haskell and I'm having the following problem:
I want to sort a String in a particular way. All the characters should be next to each other, and their general position in the resulting String should depend on how often they were present in the original String. For example:

"aabcbb" should return "caabbb"

The first idea I had was something like generally sorting the String first, then grouping the chars into lists of lists, comparing the lengths of said lists and trying to sort them in some way. 
However, I'm stuck at trying to convert a String to a list of lists of chars. I've managed my first sorting:

```
listify :: String -> [Char]
listify [] = []
listify (x:xs) = [x] ++ listify isInRest ++ listify notInRest
         where
          isInRest = [y | y <-xs, y==x]
          notInRest = [z | z <-xs, z/=x]
```

Which obviously returns a sorted list, but in order of appearance (would be "aabbbc" in my upper example). I don't really get how to proceed further.

Also, in general, I don't really understand why I can't handle the first option of my funcition in another way. I tried

```
listify :: String -> [Char]
listify (x:xs)
        | x == [] = []
        | x == "" = ""
```

I don't use both options at the same time, but I am not really sure how to handle an empty list if it's in this style since I'm getting the following errors and I'm not sure how to handle those:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All these functions already exist in the standard library. The simplest thing you can do is

```
import Data.Ord
import Data.List

f = concat . sortBy (comparing length) . group . sort
```

Or, since `length` is O(n), here is a more efficient way:

```
import Data.Ord
import Data.List
import Control.Arrow

f = concatMap snd . sortBy (comparing fst) . map (length &&& id) . group . sort
```

Also, `String` is the same thing as `[Char]`.

You can't compare `x` to `[]` here

```
listify :: String -> [Char]
listify (x:xs)
        | x == [] = []
        | x == "" = ""
```

because `x` has type `Char`, which is not a list.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think of using functions from the standard library. However, I didn't do anything regarding functional composition yet - is there another way to do this? I especially don't really understand how you're using sortBy.

Comment: @skulpt, not sure if I understood you correctly: do you want to remove these dots? If so, you can write `f x = concat (sortBy (comparing length) (group (sort x)))`. Or without parentheses, but with `($)`. However it's really better to just use function composition.

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly what I needed. It appears that I've just left out parentheses. Thanks!

Comment: @skulpt, what do you not understand about `sortBy`? It receives a function, that decides how to order elements. `comparing` constructs such function, here is the definition: `comparing p x y = compare (p x) (p y)`. In this case `x` and `y` are lists, `p` is `length`, so we compare lists by their length.

Answer (score 2):

The most natural data structure to use for this purpose is probably a priority search queue. Using one of these (which you can get from Hackage), you can use characters as keys and frequency counts as priorities. Work through all the characters in the string, bumping up that character's priority, and then in the end pull everything out in priority order.

Using the `psqueues` package,

```
import Data.IntPSQ
import Data.Foldable

buildPSQ :: (Foldable t, Ord p, Num p, Enum a) =>
            t a -> IntPSQ p ()
buildPSQ = foldl'
           (\q x -> snd $ PSQ.alter
                          (maybe ((), Just (1,()))
                                 (\(p,_) -> ((), Just (p+1,()))))
                          (fromEnum x) q)
           PSQ.empty

foldrPrio :: Ord p => (Int -> p -> v -> b -> b) -> b -> IntPSQ p v -> b    
foldrPrio k n = maybe n (\(c,p,v,r) -> k c p v (foldrPrio k n r)) . PSQ.minView

rebuild :: Enum a => IntPSQ Int t1 -> [a]
rebuild = foldrPrio (\c p _ r -> replicate p (toEnum c) ++ r) []

sortFreq :: (Foldable f, Enum a) => f a -> [a]
sortFreq = rebuild . buildPSQ
```